# How can I transpose and sum in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data in SQL Server. I want to transpose the values in  COMPONENT 1, COMPONENT 2, COMPONENT 3, COMPONENT 4 columns and sum the numbers in JUL, AUG, SEPT,OCT, NOV, DEC if any duplicate. I normally use PIVOT table in Excel but I want to do it in SQL Server to save some time.

```
CUST NAME   CUST PART#  PN#         COMPONENT 1 COMPONENET 2 COMPONENT 3 COMPONENT 4  JUL     AUG   SEP     OCT   NOV    DEC
COMPANY X   4455623    7801080R        902031     1200958           1                 2 
COMPANY X   4455622    78601080L        902031    1200958           1                 2 
COMPANY X   4455621    78601076R        902031    1200959           1                                              2    
COMPANY X   4455620    78601076L        902031    1200959           1                                              2    
COMPANY X   4455439    78601018R        900574    1200960           2                                                    12
COMPANY X   4455438   78601018L         900574    1200960           2                                                    12
COMPANY X   4455364   78601016R         900574    1200959                                                      6    6   
COMPANY X   4455361   78601016L         900574    1200959                                                      6    6   
COMPANY X   4455363   78601014R         900574    1200958                                                      6    6   
COMPANY X   4455362   78601014L         900574    1200958                                                      6    6
```

I want to get the following result

```
CUST NAME   COMP    JUL AUG    SEPT OCT   NOV DEC
---------------------------------------------------
COMPANY X   1200958  2               12   16    
COMPANY X   1200959  2               12   16    
COMPANY X   1200960  4                         24
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anything?

Comment: Show your query.

Comment: I tried pivote table in sql server but the result doesnt make sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you sample output, you do not appear to be transposing anything, rather simply aggregating on "COMPONENET 2".

The query:

```
SELECT CUST, NAME,   COMP2,
    SUM( JUL ) AS Jul, SUM( AUG ) AS AUG, SUM( SEPT ) AS SEPT,
    SUM( OCT ) AS OCT, SUM( NOV ) AS AUG, SUM( DEC ) AS DEC
FROM [table]
GROUP BY CUST, NAME,   COMP2
```

Comment: THANK YOU @Alex its good but i need merge or transpose  `COMPONENT 1, COMPONENT 2, COMPONENT 3` into one column and sum. your solution works perfect for one field but i want to do the same for `COMPONENT 1, COMPONENT 2, COMPONENT 3`

Comment: @user8066749, looking at your sample result it looks like you are grouping by [COMPONENT 2] and [PN#] and summing months. Maybe you should provide better sample results.

Comment: sorry but i mentioned in the question says i want the same for COMPONENT 1, COMPONENT 2, COMPONENT 3, COMPONENT 4

Comment: i USED UNION AND WORKS FOR ME